How to Customize Feedback Icons in nz-form-control with ng-zorro?
I'm using ng-zorro for form validation in my Angular project and I want to customize the feedback icons (success and error icons) that appear inside the input fields. By default, ng-zorro uses its own set of icons for validation feedback, but I would like to replace these with custom icons.
I have tried using suffix icon instead of using the nzHasfeedback but it removes the focus whenver i type the invalid email
